# Hackerrank diagonal difference, what's wrong with my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a square matrix, calculate the absolute difference between the sums of its diagonals.

For example, the square matrix  is shown below:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
9 8 9
```

The left-to-right diagonal =1 + 5 + 9 = 15 . The right to left diagonal =3+5+9=17 . Their absolute difference is |15-17|=2.

Function description

Complete the  diagonalDifference function in the editor below. It must return an integer representing the absolute diagonal difference.

diagonalDifference takes the following parameter:

arr: an array of integers .

Input Format

The first line contains a single integer,n , the number of rows and columns in the matrix arr. 
Each of the next n  lines describes a row,arr[i] , and consists of n space-separated integers arr[i][j] .

Sample Input

```
3
11 2 4
4 5 6
10 8 -12
```

Sample Output

```
15
```

My code:

```
def diagonalDifference(arr):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    left = 0
    right = 0

    for x in range(arr+1):
        left += arr[0 + i][0 + j]
        right += arr[0 + i][n - j]

        i += 1
        j += 1

    return abs(left - right)
```

Here's my code. I don't know what's wrong. Please help.

The Question is "Diagonal Difference" on Hackerrank.

EDIT: Second attempt

```
def diagonalDifference(arr):
    left = 0
    right = 0
    for x in range(len(arr)):
        left += arr[0+x][0+x]
        right += arr[0+x][len(arr)-x]
    return abs(left-right)
```

I get following error:

```
    right += arr[0+x][len(arr)-x]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: if `arr` is an array (of arrays), this line `for x in range(arr+1)` doesn't make much sense. You probably meant `for x in range(len(arr))`. Also `arr[0 + i][0 + j]` is always `arr[i][j]`. Finally, `i` and `j` are probably useless, as you can use `x` for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for answering!
I changed my code according to your answer but still error.. 
what's wrong ? 
sorry.. I don't know how to write code to see better on reply..

def diagonalDifference(arr):
    
    left = 0
    right = 0
    
    for x in range(len(arr)):
        
        left += arr[0+x][0+x]
        right += arr[0+x][len(arr)-x]

    return abs(left-right)

Comment: @PudgeKim I put your code inside your question, please check if I copied it correctly, as I had to guess the indentation levels

Comment: @PudgeKim also, since I don't see it, where's the code that actually reads the input? The error may be in there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access `len(arr)-x` - for x == 0 this is IndexError :

> ```
> def diagonalDifference(arr):
>     left = 0
>     right = 0
>     for x in range(len(arr)):
>         left += arr[0+x][0+x]
>         right += arr[0+x][len(arr)-x]
>     return abs(left-right)
> ```

```
arr = [[1,2],[3,4]]
len_arr = len(arr)   # len(arr) is 2, you index into  arr[0][2-0] fox x==0
                     # but arr only has arr[0][0] and arr[0][1] for x == 0
```

---

You need to sum over:

```
k[0][0], k[1][1], k[2][2], ..., k[n-1][n-1]  where n = len(k) for the forward diag
```

and

```
k[0][n-1-0], k[1][n-1-1], k[2][n-1-2], ..., k[n-1][n-1-(n-1)] for the backward diag
```

Codewise:

```
def diag (data, reverse=False):
    ld = len(data)
    if reverse:
        return sum(data[i][ld-i-1] for i in range(ld))
    else:
        return sum(data[i][i] for i in range(ld))


k = [[0,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20],[0,22,23,24,25]]

print (diag(k))          # 64
print(diag(k,True))      # 44

def absDiagDiff(data):
    return abs(diag(data)-diag(data,True))

print(absDiagDiff(k))    # 20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

#
# Complete the 'diagonalDifference' function below.
#
# The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
# The function accepts 2D_INTEGER_ARRAY arr as parameter.
#

def diagonalDifference(arr):
    diag1=0
    diag2=0
    
    for x in range(int(len(arr))):
        y=list(reversed(list(range(len(arr[x])))))
        diag1+=arr[x][x]
        diag2+=arr[x][y[x]]

    return abs(diag1-diag2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    n = int(input().strip())

    arr = []

    for _ in range(n):
        arr.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))

    result = diagonalDifference(arr)

    fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

If that can help, here's how I would of done it :

```
n = int(input())

array = []

total1 = 0
total2 = 0
index = 0
for i in range(n):
    array = [[] for n in range(n)]

for arrays in array:
    arrays += map(int,input().split())
    if len(arrays) != n:
        print(f"Error, need to be {n} by {n}")


if index == 0:
    for arrays in array:
        total1 += arrays[index]
        index += 1

elif index == n:
    for arrays in array:

        total2 += arrays[index-1]
        index -= 1

print(abs(total1-total2))
```